# Does this question belong here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, cross-posting

I've asked this question at StackOverflow, and someone suggested asking cstheory.SE as well. If it does, should I copy the question, just post a link, or get a moderator to move it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898511/problem-bobs-sale

Comment: Thanks for asking, btw. Many people don't.

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curiously, someone took inspiration from your question and has made a variant of it for this site:

[Minimum weight subforest of given cardinality](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4904/minimum-weight-subforest-of-given-cardinality)

Therefore it seems reasonable that it belongs on this site, but unfortunately it may have already been asked.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that that question is for a similar but different problem.

Comment: If you feel that question is sufficiently different, then perhaps you should write your own question. Be careful to refer to both your original StackOverflow question and the above mentioned question.

Comment: @Cyber: The question I asked matches the case when the price tags are $\{0,1\}$, I believe.